# Xcode : realm thread issue

Tags: xcode, realm

i am new to IOS development and i recently tried `realm`
the problem is that, i have to get the urls from a json file and then i put those urls in realm as an object ...and whenever i start my app again the URL variable would get the respected url from realm...
like this:

```
getUrls()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    // Query Realm for all dogs less than 2 years old
    let urls = realm.objects(UrlCollector.self).first
    let sss = realm.objects(UrlCollector.self)
    print("no of objects in did load \(sss.count)")
    loginUrl = urls!.login
    print("login url inside didload \(loginUrl)")
```

but the problem is `getUrls` method...it updates the urls using almofire

`getUrls` method:

```
Alamofire.request("<<<myurl>>>", method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if let data = response.result.value{
                   print(data)

                        let data = JSON(data)

                        for item in data["result"].arrayValue {

                            let url = UrlCollector()
                            url.login = "\(self.server)\(item["login"].stringValue)"
                            print(url.login)
                            url.changePassword = "\(self.server)\(item["changePassword"].stringValue)"
                             print(url.changePassword)
                            url.phoneNumberVerify = "\(self.server)\(item["phoneNumberVerify"].stringValue)"
                             print(url.phoneNumberVerify)
                            url.sessionCheck = "\(self.server)\(item["sessionCheck"].stringValue)"
                             print(url.sessionCheck)
                            // Get the default Realm
                            let realm = try! Realm()

                            var urls = realm.objects(UrlCollector.self)
                            // Persist your data easily
                            try! realm.write {

                                realm.delete(urls)
                                realm.add(url)
                        }

                            // Query Realm for all dogs less than 2 years old
                            urls = realm.objects(UrlCollector.self)
                            print(urls.count)
                    }
                }

                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error message:\(response.result.error)")
                break

            }
        }
    }
```

this code runs on did load

my log:

```
no of objects in did load 1
login url inside didload 
{
    result =     (
                {
            changePassword = "/iust_app/android/passwordChange.php";
            login = "/iust_app/android/login.php";
            phoneNumberVerify = "/iust_app/android/onNumberVerification.php";
            sessionCheck = "/iust_app/android/sessionCheck.php";
        }
    );
}
/iust_app/android/login.php
/iust_app/android/passwordChange.php
/iust_app/android/onNumberVerification.php
/iust_app/android/sessionCheck.php
1




print("no of objects in did load \(sss.count)")
    loginUrl = urls!.login
    print("login url inside didload \(loginUrl)")
```

as you can see these runs before the request...Please read my log lines to understand

Answer (score 0):

All network requests are executed asynchronously. If you want your code to be executed after you get a response from the server put it into the completion handler of this request.